# Feedburner knows my e-mail address?

Tags: privacy

I start up my browser on an empty cache, no passwords and no nothing stored. Log in to Stackexchange via the Google log-in option.

Next, I open feedburner.com in a second tab. (I have never had an account with feedburner.) The page greets me, "Welcome back, [e-mail address]"!

How is that possible? Apparently the log-in to SE created some kind of super cookie in my Firefox that any website that gets opened in a new tab can access. I had no idea that could happen. There are web sites that I visit that I do not want them to know my e-mail address.

If, that is, it is *only* the address and not also the password!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

When using the Google login option, you log into your Google account first, then use it to log into Stack Exchange. Since FeedBurner is owned by Google, uses Google accounts, and runs under the `.google.com` domain, it just reads the same cookie as other Google services.

Answer (score 2):

Feedburner is owned by Google; once you are logged in to your Google account, you are logged in to its services, like Gmail, Google Drive, and Feedburner too.